# Use of search function in nested if in excel

Tags: excel

i am looking to search function in nested if in excel. 
Basically , i am trying to check if certain characters are there in a string or not. If yes, it should print a name for it. else search for another characters i specify.

so,

If String Has " LA-" , it should say Lookalike ,
else if string has "Cust-" , It should say customers ,
else if string has " -Remarketing" , it should say remarketing,
else if string has " -Interest" , it should say interest.

would be really helpful if somebody has an ans for this..

Thanks..

Comment: =IF(SEARCH("LA-",A6),"LOOKALIKE", (IF(SEARCH("CUST-",A6),"Customer",(IF(SEARCH("RT-",A6),"Retargeting")))))

Comment: search returns the starting position of searched text. It seems better to use ISERROR function because search function returns error if the text is not found. so you can try something like `=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("LA-",A6)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("CUST-",A6)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("RT-",A6)),"NOT FOUND","Retargeting"),"Customer"),"LOOKALIKE")`

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("LA-",B2)),"Lookalike",(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Cust-",B2)),"Customer",(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-Remarketing",B2)),"Remarketing",((IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-Inter",B2)),"Interest","Not Found"))))))))
```

[image: excel_example]